# bad_cast_exception: Error while starting up Nodeos

Tags: nodeos

I get an error starting up nodeos. I am trying to run a second node on another account and start it as a non block producer.

Whenever I start, I get a bad_cast_exception.

> ```
> > Invalid cast from type 'string_type' to Object
> >     {"type":"string_type"}
> >     nodeos  variant.cpp:583 get_object
> ```

The command I am using:

```
nodeos
```

My error log:

```
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.034 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:556          plugin_initialize    ] initializing chain plugin
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.035 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:408          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'PREACTIVATE_FEATURE' (with digest of '0ec7e080177b2c02b278d5088611686b49d739925a92d9bfcacd7fc6b74053bd') is enabled without activation restrictions
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.035 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:395          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'ONLY_LINK_TO_EXISTING_PERMISSION' (with digest of '1a99a59d87e06e09ec5b028a9cbb7749b4a5ad8819004365d02dc4379a8b7241') is enabled with preactivation required
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.035 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:395          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'FORWARD_SETCODE' (with digest of '2652f5f96006294109b3dd0bbde63693f55324af452b799ee137a81a905eed25') is enabled with preactivation required
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.035 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:395          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'REPLACE_DEFERRED' (with digest of 'ef43112c6543b88db2283a2e077278c315ae2c84719a8b25f25cc88565fbea99') is enabled with preactivation required
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.035 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:395          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'NO_DUPLICATE_DEFERRED_ID' (with digest of '4a90c00d55454dc5b059055ca213579c6ea856967712a56017487886a4d4cc0f') is enabled with preactivation required
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.035 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:395          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'RAM_RESTRICTIONS' (with digest of '4e7bf348da00a945489b2a681749eb56f5de00b900014e137ddae39f48f69d67') is enabled with preactivation required
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.035 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:395          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'DISALLOW_EMPTY_PRODUCER_SCHEDULE' (with digest of '68dcaa34c0517d19666e6b33add67351d8c5f69e999ca1e37931bc410a297428') is enabled with preactivation required
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.035 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:395          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'ONLY_BILL_FIRST_AUTHORIZER' (with digest of '8ba52fe7a3956c5cd3a656a3174b931d3bb2abb45578befc59f283ecd816a405') is enabled with preactivation required
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.035 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:395          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'RESTRICT_ACTION_TO_SELF' (with digest of 'ad9e3d8f650687709fd68f4b90b41f7d825a365b02c23a636cef88ac2ac00c43') is enabled with preactivation required
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.035 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:395          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'FIX_LINKAUTH_RESTRICTION' (with digest of 'e0fb64b1085cc5538970158d05a009c24e276fb94e1a0bf6a528b48fbc4ff526') is enabled with preactivation required
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.035 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:395          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'GET_SENDER' (with digest of 'f0af56d2c5a48d60a4a5b5c903edfb7db3a736a94ed589d0b797df33ff9d3e1d') is enabled with preactivation required
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.038 nodeos    block_log.cpp:125             open                 ] Log is nonempty
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.038 nodeos    block_log.cpp:152             open                 ] Index is nonempty
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.038 nodeos    http_plugin.cpp:465           plugin_initialize    ] configured http to listen on 127.0.0.1:8889
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.039 nodeos    mongo_db_plugin.cpp:1587      plugin_initialize    ] initializing mongo_db_plugin
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.039 nodeos    mongo_db_plugin.cpp:1673      plugin_initialize    ] connecting to mongodb://eos2:Eef9shoujee@127.0.0.1:27017/EOS2
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.039 nodeos    mongo_db_plugin.cpp:1436      init                 ] init mongo
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.055 nodeos    mongo_db_plugin.cpp:1523      init                 ] starting db plugin thread
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.055 nodeos    http_plugin.cpp:412           operator()           ] configured http with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
error 2019-08-30T07:21:14.055 nodeos    main.cpp:114                  main                 ] 7 bad_cast_exception: Bad Cast
Invalid cast from type 'string_type' to Object
    {"type":"string_type"}
    nodeos  variant.cpp:583 get_object
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.060 nodeos    mongo_db_plugin.cpp:1357      ~mongo_db_plugin_imp ] mongo_db_plugin shutdown in process please be patient this can take a few minutes
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.060 mongodb   mongo_db_plugin.cpp:445       consume_blocks       ] draining queue, size: 0
info  2019-08-30T07:21:14.060 mongodb   mongo_db_plugin.cpp:507       consume_blocks       ] mongo_db_plugin consume thread shutdown gracefully
```

I tried changing the config.ini, adding the configurations one by one, but nothing works. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting this error, it could be due to an error in your `logging.json`.

Check your logging.json from error or visit the [documentation](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/logging) for logging to copy a sample logging.json into your existing logging.json.